# How to perform an if else statement in a SQL Server function

Tags: sql-server, function

I need to return a 1 in case the dniPaciente is found in the Paciente table, otherwise the value 0. However, I don't know how I would have to do it to return 0 if the paciente did not exist.

For the moment, I have done the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION busquedaPaciente(@dniPaciente varchar(8)) 
RETURNS INT   
AS    
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @encontrado int  

    SELECT @encontrado = 1   
    FROM Paciente   
    WHERE dniPaciente =@dniPaciente

    RETURN @encontrado
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a CASE statement in your query instead of a user-defined function.  Something like this

```
select a.id, case when p.dniPaciente is null then 0 else 1 end as one_or_zero
from aTable a
     left join Paciente p on a.id=p.id;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need `CASE WHEN EXISTS`:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION busquedaPaciente(@dniPaciente varchar(8)) 
RETURNS bit
WITH SCHEMABINDING  -- preferable if you can to schema-bind
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CAST(CASE WHEN EXISTS(
        SELECT 1   
        FROM Paciente   
        WHERE dniPaciente =@dniPaciente)
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit);
END;
GO
```

---

**But scalar functions have massive downsides for performance.** You are far better off using an inline Table-Valued Function for this:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION busquedaPaciente(@dniPaciente varchar(8)) 
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING  -- preferable if you can to schema-bind
AS RETURN
    SELECT IsExist = CAST(CASE WHEN EXISTS(
        SELECT 1   
        FROM dbo.Paciente   
        WHERE dniPaciente =@dniPaciente)
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit);
GO
```

You use it like this:

```
SELECT Paciente.IsExist
FROM myTable
CROSS APPLY dbo.busquedaPaciente (dniPaciente) AS Paciente
```

Comment: `@encontrado` is STILL not defined in your first function. And why do you need to assign a variable in the return statement? And why cast to bit when the function returns an int?

Comment: Whoops sloppy of me

Comment: @Charlieface. Excellent contribution. Thanks a lot. It has been a great help to me.